# How can I debug VNC screen repainting issues?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I have what some might consider a trivial use for VNC, but I'd like to get it to work and it's technically interesting to me.

My use case is that I'd like sometimes to be able to control my desktop from my living room while watching tv.  The desktop runs Ubuntu, currently 12.04, but that may change soon.  I'm using the default Vino server.

I'd like to control it from my iPad and I have a nicely performing WiFi.  I got the well-regarded (if reviews can be believed) app Vnc Viewer for the iPad.

It's not working as well as I'd hoped.  The problem is the speed of repainting.  It's abysmally slow.  I can click a close button, walk over to the desktop and see that the window has closed, but on the iPad, the VNC Client won't show the close for minutes if ever.  I've noticed that CLOSING windows takes a lot longer to update than to open them.

So the question is is this primarily client or server-caused?  And if server-caused what can be done about it?  Is Vino the best client or is something else better?

Answer (score 1):

According to RealVNC tech support (the authors of VNC Viewer client IPad software), their server software works better than Vino, with VNC Viewer and I have found that to be true.  With that in use, the viewer is much more responsive.  They have a free Linux server package for noncommercial use.

- https://realvnc.com/download/vnc/latest

It appears that the Vino-VNC Viewer combo is less than ideal.  Going with the free RealVNC Server instead of Vino is an improvement.  Is there another solution on the iPad client side that works better with Vino?